# How do I return all non deleted messages of a current thread in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Having a little trouble figuring out a way to display messages for users message threads depending on which ones have been deleted and not. Deleted messages "sender_status or recipient_status" will change from 0 to 1 on deletion of a message. Currently to display a list of users message threads in their inbox I use:

e.g.

```
current_user = User.find(2)
current_user.message_threads
```

This grabs all their message_threads with 0 sender or recipient statuses.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages
  has_many :message_threads
```

Nice and easy but what I would like to do now is some how set up something that enables me to be able to grab messages with 0 sender or recipient statuses from a current thread. So if I was to type:

```
one_thread = current_user.message_threads.first
```

From this thread I'd want to be able to easily grab the only messages I needed. Would like to put something in the message_thread model so I could eventually type out:

```
current_user.message_threads.first.messages

#or

one_thread.messages
```

and have only the messages I needed loaded and the ones with "1" statuses ignored.

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages
  has_many :message_threads

  def message_threads
    MessageThread.where([ '(sender_id = ? AND sender_status = 0) OR (recipient_id = ? AND recipient_status = 0)', self.id, self.id ])
  end

  def messages
    Message.where([ '(sender_id = ? AND sender_status = 0) OR (recipient_id = ? AND recipient_status = 0)', self.id, self.id ])
  end
```

**MessageThread model:**

```
class MessageThread < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages
```

**Message model:**

```
  class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

    acts_as_tree
    has_one :message_thread
```

I tried experimenting with joins but this didn't work out well for me.

```
def messages
  joins(:messages).merge(  Message.where([ '(parent_id = ? AND sender_status = 0) OR (parent_id = ? AND recipient_status = 0)',self.message_id, self.message_id ]) )
end
```

Help would be much appreciate.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that `one_thread` is returning a `MessageThread` object, and then you're trying to get the user id by calling `self.id`, but it's being called on the wrong model.

I haven't tried this code but it might work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.threads_in_inbox
    message_threads.where('(sender_id = ? AND sender_status = 0) OR (recipient_id = ? AND recipient_status = 0)', self.id, self.id)
  end
end

class MessageThread < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inbox_messages
    messages.where('(sender_id = ? AND sender_status = 0) OR (recipient_id = ? AND recipient_status = 0)', self.user.id, self.user.id)
    # this hits the database 1 extra time however due to self.user.id
    # you could change it to inbox_messages(user_id) and pass in the id manually
  end
end

first_thread = current_user.threads_in_inbox.first
first_thread.inbox_messages
```

In your question it seems like you're overriding the association queries generated by rails (message_threads and messages) - not sure if it's on purpose but I changed it above.

Also, I think you can remove the duplication and do the following:

```
where('(sender_id = ?) AND (sender_status = 0 OR recipient_status = 0)', self.id)
```